# Flutter:how to delay the build method for sometime

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, token

I'm working on my project which includes signup and login and I'm also saving JSON web token (in the SharedPreferences) received from the API upon logged in or signed up.

I've created an async method which detects whether the the token is already saved inside sharedPreferences (so the user is authenticated and authorized to get access to home page without any need to enter username and password again)

when I use this method inside the initState() method of the landing page(which is in my case,the page that display the login form),
the landing page shows up for 1 second or less and then the token becomes available after the Future data returned by checkAuthentication becomes available ,
and then the user is redirected to the home page,

I want to make the landing page does not appear at all unless the token is not found

```
//by the way AuthData is just a custom class

Future<AuthData> checkAuthentication() async {
    AuthData authData = new AuthData();
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if(preferences.containsKey("token")){
      authData.token =  preferences.get("token");
      return authData;
    }
    return null;
  }


// initState method
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
checkAuthentication().then((AuthData data){
   if(data != null){
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/home-page", 
ModalRoute.withName(null));
      }    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setState

```
bool isLogin = false;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
checkAuthentication().then((AuthData data){
       setState(() {
        if(!data)
        isLogin = true;
      });
      if(isLogin)
         Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/home-page",
         ModalRoute.withName(null));
  });
}
```